# How do I call up the "last command" in eclipse osgi console?

Tags: eclipse, command, osgi

How do I call up the "last command" in eclipse osgi console?

Is there a similar behavior as in Windows Explorer of using the up/down arrows to recall last executed commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the [initial incubator project](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/incubator/console/design-doc.php) and the [OSGi console tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/OSGi/article.html) mention that:

> The history is a buffer, which saves each command line when a new line character is read, just before passing it to the shell input stream. **With the up and down arrow the user can navigate through the history**.
>
> Via `-console 5555` you can open a port to which you can telnet.
> If you telnet to the OSGi console the new console included in Eclipse 4.2 support tab completion and a history of the commands.